# How do I get a file path without extension in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have an absolute path in a variable in my powershell 2.0 script. I want to strip off the extension but keep the full path and file name. Easiest way to do that?

So if I have `C:\Temp\MyFolder\mytextfile.fake.ext.txt` in a variable called, say `$file`

I want to return

`C:\Temp\MyFolder\mytextfile.fake.ext`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

if is a `[string]` type:

```
 $file.Substring(0, $file.LastIndexOf('.'))
```

if is a `[system.io.fileinfo]` type:

```
join-path $File.DirectoryName  $file.BaseName
```

or you can cast it:

```
join-path ([system.io.fileinfo]$File).DirectoryName  ([system.io.fileinfo]$file).BaseName
```

Comment: It is a [string] type. If I wanted to make it more robust and cope with a variable extension length? What if I have a `.pl` file or a `.blahblah` file?

Comment: `$file.Substring(0, $file.LastIndexOf('.'))` is a good one. But mind 2 cases: 1) no extension and a dot in the middle: 'C:\Tests.1\FileNoExtension' results in 'C:\Tests'; 2) no dots at all results in an exception.

Comment: @RomanKuzmin You're right... thank you. I hope that who read my answer read your comment too and know all his files have an extesion or using code with cast to [Fileinfo] ;)

Answer (score 24):

Here is the best way I prefer AND other examples:

```
$FileNamePath
(Get-Item $FileNamePath).Extension
(Get-Item $FileNamePath).Basename
(Get-Item $FileNamePath).Name
(Get-Item $FileNamePath).DirectoryName
(Get-Item $FileNamePath).FullName
```

Comment: Because there are more efficient solutions instead of complex code.

Comment: It would be nice if you provided some comments beside each line showing what exactly would be returned.

Comment: A big drawback here is that this requires the file to exist.

Answer (score 6):

```
# the path
$file = 'C:\Temp\MyFolder\mytextfile.fake.ext.txt'

# using regular expression
$file -replace '\.[^.\\/]+$'

# or using System.IO.Path (too verbose but useful to know)
Join-Path ([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($file)) ([System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($file))
```

Comment: If you have access to the file you could also use: `Get-Item $yourpathvar | % { $_.FullName -replace $_.Extension }`

Comment: @Graimer: I think this is not correct. 1) string `$_.Extension` may also be in the middle of the path. 2) It may contain special regex characters like `[]`.

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't see the hidden regex characters in his sample. MOST people don't use special characters in an extension. As for your point one, please show me a sample where the extension is in the middle of a path(which exists). I'm not saying mine was better, just a easier to read version for normal day use :)

Comment: In 'C:\Tests.1\Test.1' after replacing '.1' we will get 'C:\Tests\Test' (not correct). And, yes, it exists, I have just created one :)

Comment: +1 thanks =) didn't think about that. but again, that's not normal day situation, at least not in my company

Comment: @David Martin suggests yet another way using `get-item` BUT the file must
exist: `Get-Item $file | %{ join-path -path $_.DirectoryName -ChildPath
$_.basename}`. It is worth to be posted as a separate answer but @C.B.'s
version is very similar and does not require a file to exist and be obtained.

Answer (score 6):

You should use the simple .NET framework method, instead of cobbling together path parts or doing replacements.

```
PS> [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($file)
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: OP asked how to get the file _path_ without an extension.  This does not do that.  Rather, `::GetFileNameWithoutExtension()` returns the file name stripped of both the path and the extension.

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of whether `$file` is `string` or `FileInfo` object:

```
(Get-Item $file).BaseName
```

Comment: This requires that the file actually exists.